# Random string vs Guid

Tags: c#, cryptography

I need a random string of 32 characters to be used as salt for hashing some value.  This random string is generated per user.

What is the difference between generating a guid per user and using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider?

Comment: Hashing does not take a random string as input, it just takes a message. Maybe you want to try a specific, higher level algorithm or protocol that merely *uses* a hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this, I understood the difference
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/23/10309199.aspx

> GUIDs are designed to be unique, not random
>
> The GUID generation algorithm was designed for uniqueness. It was not designed for randomness or for unpredictability. Indeed, if you
>   look at an earlier discussion, you can see that so-called Algorithm 1
>   is non-random and totally predictable. If you use an Algorithm 1 GUID
>   generator to assign GUIDs to candidates, you'll find that the GUIDs
>   are assigned in numerically ascending order (because the timestamp
>   increases). The customer's proposed algorithm would most likely end up
>   choosing for jury duty the first N people entered into the system
>   after a 32-bit timer rollover. Definitely not random.
>
> Similarly, the person who wanted to use a GUID for password generation would find that the passwords are totally predictable if
>   you know what time the GUID was generated and which computer generated
>   the GUID (which you can get by looking at the final six bytes from
>   some other password-GUID). Totally-predictable passwords are probably
>   not a good idea.

Comment: Come on, though.  Nobody has used an Algorithm 1 GUID in over 20 years, have they?

Answer (score 2):

It's the difference between generating a *unique key* and generating 32 *random characters*. That's about it. Do what you intend to do.

If you need some way of identifying that user uniquely, even if databases are merged, use a GUID. If you need a salt for hashing a password, then use a random `byte[]`. Neither of them works well in the other context.

Comment: random string can never be used where uniqueness is required, but a unique string CAN ALSO be used where randomness is required... is this wrong?

Comment: Yes. A GUID's defining property is its uniqueness. How that is achieved varies depending on the generation algorithm. There are pseudo-random GUIDs, yes, but there are also those that contain the MAC address of the computer that generated it and a time stamp. Those are in no way random at all. And if you go so far to use a GUID for randomness by requiring that it's a v4 GUID, then you can just as well use a PRNG and be done with it. No need to drag a GUID into that.